# how to uninstall TOR from centOS?

Tags: onion-routing, tor-install

I installed Tor on a centOS server by executing this command:

```
#yum install tor
```

Now how should I remove it? What command should I execute to completely remove Tor?

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove the Tor package by using:

```
yum remove tor
```

From `man yum`:

> remove or erase
>
> Are used to remove the specified packages from the system as well as
>   removing any packages which depend on the package being removed.
>   remove operates on groups, files, provides and filelists just like the
>   "install" command